# Select from multiple tables where 1 record has more than 1 match in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, for example one with a person ID, name and food ID for an order and the second with the food ID and food name. I want to join these and return the ID, name, Food ID and Food Name but only for instances where the count of IDs and Food names are > 1 like below. Unfortunately when I try to do this I either get NULL instances from ID or it pulls the Food IDs I'm trying to exclude

Person

| ID | Name | Food_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 3 |
| 2 | Jill | 2 |
| 3 | Jack | 1 |
| 1 | Joe | 1 |
| 2 | Jill | 3 |
| 3 | Jack | 3 |
| 1 | Joe | 4 |
| 2 | Jill | 4 |
| 3 | Jack | 4 |

Food

| Food ID | Food |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Meat - Fish |
| 2 | Veg - Potato |
| 3 | Meat - Chicken |
| 4 | Veg - Broccoli |

| ID | Name | Food_ID | Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 3 | Meat - Chicken |
| 1 | Joe | 1 | Meat - Fish |
| 3 | Jill | 1 | Meat - Fish |
| 3 | Jill | 3 | Meat - Chicken |

I can do it using a temp table to get count of IDs `where food like '%Meat%' and count (p.ID) > 1` but I need it to run in just a select query and I've no ID how to approach it as including a where exists just returns me NULL IDs. Apologies for how bad my SQL is but I haven't used it in years and am used to doing all my aggregation in Excel so have little idea how I'm meant to approach it, it's probably a really simple solution

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, f.Food_ID, f.Name
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Food f ON p.Food_ID = f.Food_ID
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT COUNT(p.ID), COUNT(f.Food_ID)
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN Food f ON p.Food_ID = f.Food_ID
    WHERE f.Food LIKE '%Meat%'
    GROUP BY p.ID
    HAVING COUNT(p.id) > 1 
)
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Person
    JOIN Food ON Food.Food_ID = Person.Food_ID
WHERE
    Person.ID IN (
        SELECT
            Person.ID
        FROM
            Person
            JOIN Food ON Food.Food_ID = Person.Food_ID
        WHERE
            Food.Food LIKE '%meat%'
        GROUP BY
            Person.ID
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
        )
ORDER BY
    Person.ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` to get `GROUP BY p.ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, then get the other column values you need in your main query with a `JOIN` to your `CTE` using the `p.ID` column.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    p.ID
    FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Food f ON p.Food_ID = f.Food_ID
  WHERE f.Food LIKE '%Meat%'
  GROUP BY p.ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT 
  p.ID, 
  p.Name, 
  f.Food_ID, 
  f.Food
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Food f ON p.Food_ID = f.Food_ID
INNER JOIN cte ON p.ID = cte.ID
WHERE f.Food LIKE '%Meat%'
ORDER BY p.ID ASC
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gRXwqlYU?hide=56).

**Result:**

| ID | Name | Food_ID | Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 3 | Meat - Chicken |
| 1 | Joe | 1 | Meat - Fish |
| 3 | Jack | 1 | Meat - Fish |
| 3 | Jack | 3 | Meat - Chicken |

**Note:** Based on your provided data, I believe `Jack` should be listed in your result set, *not* `Jill`.